# Cambiar el color de fondo de una fila DataGrid

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, wpf, datagrid

Necesito cambiar el fondo de una fila de mi DataGrid con una condicional. Mi DataGrid tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="5" x:Name="FamiliaDataGrid" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}" CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}" RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="NÚMERO DE PARTE" CanUserResize="False" Width="130" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding NumeroParte}" x:Name="numerop"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="DESCRIPCIÓN" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" Width="380" Binding="{Binding Descripcion}" x:Name="descripcion"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="REFERENCIA" CanUserResize="False" Width="180" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Referencia}" x:Name="referencia"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="UNIDAD" CanUserResize="False" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Unidad}" x:Name="unidad"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SUBENSAMBLE" CanUserResize="False" Width="115" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding SubEns}" x:Name="subens"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PRECIO USD" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" Width="150" Binding="{Binding PrecioUSD}" x:Name="preciousd"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PRECIO MXN" CanUserResize="False" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding PrecioMXN}" x:Name="preciomxn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="OBSERVACIONES" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" Width="280" Binding="{Binding Observaciones}" x:Name="observaciones"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="REVISIÓN" CanUserResize="False" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Revision}" x:Name="revision"/>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn  IsReadOnly="True" Width="85">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource gridEditButton}" x:Name="gridEdit">
                                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="PencilOutline" Style="{StaticResource gridButtonIcon}"/>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource gridRemoveButton}" Margin="5 0 0 0" x:Name="gridEliminar">
                                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="DeleteOutline" Style="{StaticResource gridButtonIcon}"/>
                                        </Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

En mi DataGrid tiene conexión a una BD en SQL SERVER donde se almacenan los datos. No sé si es posible cambiar el fondo de una fila si en mi columna "Número de parte" aparece la palabra "OCUPADO"

Answer (score 0):

1.- Creas un convertidor, este elemento se encarga en convertir un dato a un color especifico, por ejemplo `OCUPADO` a rojo

Aquí un ejemplo muy básico

```
public class ColorCellConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    => value switch
    {
        "OCUPADO" => new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        "NO OCUPADO" => new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
        "ELIMINADO" => new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green),
        _ => new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
    };
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

2.- Crear un `CellStyle`, tú ya tienes uno así debes integrar esto al tuyo.

Lo importante es hacer el binding a la propiedad deseada e invocar al convertirdor

```
<Style x:Key="NumParteStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=NumeroParte, Converter={StaticResource ColorCellConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

3.- Ejemplo completo

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ColorCellConverter x:Key="ColorCellConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="NumParteStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=NumeroParte, Converter={StaticResource ColorCellConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="5" CellStyle="{StaticResource NumParteStyle}" x:Name="FamiliaDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            
            <DataGrid.Columns>
              
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="NÚMERO DE PARTE" CanUserResize="False" Width="130" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding NumeroParte}" x:Name="numerop"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DESCRIPCIÓN"  IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" Width="380" Binding="{Binding Descripcion}" x:Name="descripcion"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="REFERENCIA" CanUserResize="False" Width="180" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Referencia}" x:Name="referencia"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="UNIDAD" CanUserResize="False" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Unidad}" x:Name="unidad"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="SUBENSAMBLE" CanUserResize="False" Width="115" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding SubEns}" x:Name="subens"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PRECIO USD" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" Width="150" Binding="{Binding PrecioUSD}" x:Name="preciousd"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PRECIO MXN" CanUserResize="False" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding PrecioMXN}" x:Name="preciomxn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="OBSERVACIONES" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" Width="280" Binding="{Binding Observaciones}" x:Name="observaciones"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="REVISIÓN" CanUserResize="False" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Revision}" x:Name="revision"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
      
    </Grid>
</Window>
```